# appendChild sólo me inserta un elemento

Tags: javascript, dom

Tengo un botón para insertar un `H1` mediante el método `appendChild()`, pero solo lo inserta una vez. No consigo que cada vez que pulso el botón me inserte un nuevo `H1`.

Os dejo el código...

```
<button id="crearH1" value="crearH1" onclick="crearH1()">Crear H1</button>
<button id="eliminarH1" value="eliminarH1" onclick="eliminarH1()">Eliminar H1</button>

<script>
    
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");

    function crearH1(){
        h1.innerText = "H1";
        document.body.appendChild(h1);
    }

    function eliminarH1(){
        document.body.removeChild(h1);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Lee [answer], [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ya lo he visto (me ha costado un rato :) ), el problema está en que el método createElement() lo tengo fuera de la función. Solucionado!!

Comment: Si necesitas hacer un comentario de ese estilo no uses la sección de respuestas, simplemente pon un comentario en la respuesta de la persona que te haya ayudado, y si no puedes hacerlo por no tener reputacion, basta con darle voto positivo o marcarla como la mejor con ✔